# Android - Printscreen (Camera + views)

Tags: android, camera, screenshot, rootview

My application is using Camera and some components over the camera like buttons and a transparent layout for the user to draw.

At this moment im able to see the camera and draw on a top layer (transparent).

I can save the picture from camera by:

> camera.takepicture()

Result: Picture from camera without components (what i drew over it)

And i can take a picture from MyView (what i drew on transparent layout)

```
this.getWindow().getDecorView();
//create a bitmap and save it to file..
```

Result: Picture from the root view with black background instead of transparent, and no camera..

How can i combine Camera and rootView in a picture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could explore this [recipe](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4576) It stores the screen view to the PDF though.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela i didnt tried but as i understand it will save me the canvas only. I need to save the complete screen: camera + view(canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must merge the SurfaceView (with camera preview) and the other views manually.

When you get `this.getWindow().getDecorView()`, you know what rectangle is filled by camera preview, and you can get the relevant pixels from a preview callback: [camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) (it may be significantly faster than `takePicture()`).

Maybe, you must apply alpha-blending to reproduce effect of semi-transparent widgets over the camera preview.